# The number of incidences between points and parabolas on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, additive-combinatorics, incidence-geometry

I was reading Adam Sheffer's book "Polynomial Methods and Incidence Theory" and I tried to solve the following exercise:

> **Exercise 1.1** Construct a set $\mathcal{P}$ of $m$ points and a set $\Gamma$ of $n$
> parabolas that are defined by equations of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$,
> such that $I(\mathcal{P},\Gamma)=\Theta(m^{1/2}n^{5/6})$, where
> $I(\mathcal{P},\Gamma)=|\{(p,\gamma)\in\mathcal{P}\times
>  \Gamma:p\in\gamma\}|$. (*Hint:* Adat the proof of Claim 1.3.)

After thinking a bit, I think I figured out how to solve this problem, but I'm kind of stuck at the last step.

*Proof.* Let $r=\left\lfloor \frac{m^{1/2}}{3^{1/2}n^{1/6}}\right\rfloor$ and $s=\left\lfloor \frac{(3n)^{1/2}}{m^{1/2}}\right\rfloor$. Consider $$\mathcal{P}:=\{(i,j)\in \mathbb{Z}^2: 1\leq i\leq r,\ 1\leq j\leq 3r^2s\},$$
$$\Gamma:=\{y=ax^2+bx+c: 1\leq a\leq s,\ 1\leq b\leq rs,\ 1\leq c\leq r^2s\}.$$

1. Assume that $\frac{m^{1/2}}{3^{1/2}n^{1/6}}\geq 2$ and $\frac{(3n)^{1/2}}{m^{1/2}}\geq 2$. This assumption implies that $r,s\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$. I made the previous assumption because I am about to use this: if $x\geq 2$, then $x/2\leq \lfloor x\rfloor \leq x$. It implies that $\frac{m}{16}\leq |\mathcal{P}|\leq m$ and $\frac{n}{64}\leq |\Gamma|\leq n$. By definition of $I(\mathcal{P},\Gamma)$, we have $$I(\mathcal{P},\Gamma)=\sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma}|\{p\in \mathcal{P}:p\in \gamma\}|.$$

We notice that for each $\gamma\in \Gamma$ which is defined as $y=ax^2+bx+c$, we have $\{p\in \mathcal{P}:p\in \gamma\}=\{(x,ax^2+bx+c):1\leq x\leq r\}$. Therefore, $I(\mathcal{P},\Gamma)=r|\Gamma|$. One can easily compute that $\frac{m^{1/2}n^{5/6}}{256}\leq r|\Gamma|\leq m^{1/2}n^{5/6}$. Moreover, we notice that $\exists \widehat{\mathcal{P}}\ \exists \widehat{\Gamma} (\widehat{\mathcal{P}}\supset \mathcal{P}, \widehat{\Gamma}\supset \Gamma, |\widehat{\mathcal{P}}|=m, |\widehat{\Gamma}|=n)$ with the following property:  $I(\widehat{\mathcal{P}},\widehat{\Gamma})=I(\mathcal{P},\Gamma)$. We just add some points and some parabolas so that they don't give new incidences.

We can summarize this part as follows: for any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3n\geq 4m, m^3\geq 12^3n$ there exists a set $\widehat{\mathcal{P}}$ of $m$ points and a set $\widehat{\Gamma}$ of $n$ parabolas such that $$\frac{m^{1/2}n^{5/6}}{256}\leq I(\widehat{\mathcal{P}},\widehat{\Gamma})\leq m^{1/2}n^{5/6} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad I(\widehat{\mathcal{P}},\widehat{\Gamma})=\Theta(m^{1/2}n^{5/6}).$$ This part looks good to me.

But I am wondering how to handle the case when $3n<4m$ or $m^3<12^3n$, i.e., $n=O(m)$ or $m^3=O(n)$. I have no idea how to handle these cases. I'd be grateful if someone can show how to do it.